# CakePHP Issue with saveAll()

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm having a problem with CakePHP's saveAll() I was hoping someone could shed some light on.

I have a form which collects information to be saved for two models... Person and Inquiry. I believe the data are being sent correctly, but it's simply not saving the Inquiry data. It's returning a validation error, but there is no validation set up in the Inquiry model, and if I remove 'deep' => true from the People controller, it saves those fields fine.

**Data It Posts**

```
Array
(
    [Person] => Array
        (
            [first_name] => Test
            [middle_name] => 
            [last_name] => User
            [gender] => M
            [date_of_birth] => Array
                (
                    [month] => 02
                    [day] => 07
                    [year] => 1994
                )

            [address] => 1234 Main St
            [address_apt] => 
            [address_city] => Somewhere
            [address_state] => OH
            [address_zip] => 304982
            [address_country] => US
            [phone_cell] => (555) 555-5555
            [permission_to_text] => 1
            [phone_home] => (555) 555-5556
            [email_address] => test@user.com
            [preferred_contact] => text_cell
            [Inquiry] => Array
                (
                    [admit_type] => FR
                    [admit_term] => FA2014
                    [parent_first_name] => Mom
                    [parent_last_name] => User
                    [parent_email] => mom@user.com
                    [hs_name] => Columbus Downtown High School
                    [hs_ceeb_id] => 365210
                    [hs_homeschooled] => 0
                    [hs_grad_year] => Array
                        (
                            [year] => 2014
                        )

                    [coll_name] => 
                    [coll_ceeb_id] => 
                    [coll_major] => 
                    [coll_year] => 
                    [admit_major] => 1
                    [admit_minor] => 4
                )

            [social_facebook] => 
        )

)
```

**Value of $this->Person->validationErrors after Posting**

```
Array
(
    [Inquiry] => Array
        (
            [hs_homeschooled] => Array
                (
                )

            [coll_name] => Array
                (
                )

            [coll_ceeb_id] => Array
                (
                )

            [coll_major] => Array
                (
                )

            [coll_year] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

**Model - Inquiry**

```
<?php
class Inquiry extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array('Person');
}
```

**Controller**

```
<?php
class PeopleController extends AppController {
  public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Country', 'State', 'Major', 'Minor', 'Term');

  public function index() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {

            $this->Person->create();
            if ($this->Person->saveAll($this->request->data, array('deep' => true))) {
                print_r($this->request->data);
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your post has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
            print_r($errors = $this->Person->validationErrors);
            $this->set('errors', $errors = $this->Person->validationErrors);
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to add.'));
        }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Model::saveAll()` is a [wrapper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveall-array-data-null-array-options-array) of `saveMany` or `saveAssociated`.

Since you're not passing data in a numerical indexed array, i.e.

```
array(
    0 => array(...),
    1 => array(...),
)
```

it means `saveAssociated` is called. What you're apparently trying to do is to save a **new** `Person` together with the associations (`Inquiry`). If you [read through the manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-related-model-data-hasone-hasmany-belongsto) you'll come to this paragraph:

> If neither of the associated model records exists in the system yet
>   (for example, you want to save a new User and their related Profile
>   records at the same time), you’ll need to first save the primary, or
>   parent model.

So you obviously need to save the `Person` first and then all associations.

Comment: Thank you! I took a look in the documentation but I missed that line.